# Router to create this baseboard?

Tags: router, router-bit, router-table

I have old baseboards in our house and need to replace just a two foot section. I figure it would be cheapest for me to attempt to make my own. I had a guy work on our house a few years back that needed to do exactly that and left me a small sample of what he made, which matches perfectly. I assume using a router would be the best bet, but what type of bit should I use to get this shape? This will be my first router attempt but I figured I would play around and see if this would be something I could get close. I could probably get access to a router table if need be too.

[image]

[image]

Comment: this is a duplicate of a question (with answer) on Home Improvement. https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/120366/router-bit-for-baseboards

Answer (score 3):

You could do this using a router and a matching bit of course but it would be far more rational to figure out how to do it using a combination of common bits. That is if you wanted to use a router.

In a fully equipped workshop probably the simplest and fastest way to create short lengths of this profile would be accurate saw cuts (using a table saw) followed by scraping or sanding to smooth and complete the profile.

In theory the entire profile could be done using a scratch stock, although removing the bulk of the waste beforehand would be wise, but probably best to work it in sections.

The way I would do it I think would be to get as close as possible by sawing (hand sawing in my case), then planing, followed by scraping to complete the profile and smooth as necessary.

On something as small as this (especially in softwood) the roundovers can be done purely by sanding but my preference with radii of approximately this size is to use a block plane to do most of it, leaving minimal sanding to finish off.

**Note:** make a longer section than you need, then saw the mitres on the ends only when you're completely done shaping.